# How could I customize Bootstrap5 in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

guys,I am use Vue3 and Bootstrap 5.Everything work great unless I want to customize the Bootstrap default theme.
For example,I want to change the primary color, I create a `custom.scss` in `"src\scss"`,the content is:

```
// Default variable overrides
$primary:#255232;
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then,I import the `custom.scss` in `main.js`,the content in js is:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
//Import scss here
import "scss/custom.scss";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js";
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

But It comes an Error :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                   

This dependency was not found:

* scss/custom.scss in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save scss/custom.scss
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.
tmp'
```

What should I do to fix this problem ? Thanks.

```
Here is my project structure:
    my-project/
    ├──src/
    │   │──scss/
    │   │    └── custom.scss
    │   └────────main.js
    └──node_modules/
         └── bootstrap/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
I try to use file watcher to solve this problem . But I think there is an easier solution , I appreciate it if anyone can tell me , thank you !

Here is my solution :
I use WebStrom and add File Wtacher to scss file . The scss content:

```
// Default variable overrides
$primary:#255232;
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I place it in `/src/scss/custom.scss`

In the `main.js` add the `scss` after file watcher convert in to `css` :

```
import "../src/scss/custom.css";
```

Comment: I think it is an excellent solution.

Comment: Instead of `@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/..."` you should be able to use `@import "~bootstrap/..."`. In CSS `~` is alias for `<rootDir>/node_modules/`. Not sure what exactly adds this alias or where. But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

-First include sass and sass-loader to use scss in Vue:

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader
```

-Now inside `src` folder create a file name it `custom.scss`

-inside `custom.scss` define your variable overrides.

```
$primary: #14213D;
$secondary: #D62828;

// Include Bootstrap SCSS files
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Then import that single SCSS file into your main.js file

```
import 'custom.scss'
```

and you're good to go!!

NB: You can find all of the possible variables and elements in node_modules/bootstrap/scss

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Run this:

```
npm i -D sass
```

> 2. Create:

```
/src/scss/custom.scss
```

> 3. Add in custom.scss:

```
$primary: teal;
//customize here
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

> 4. Add in main.js:

```
import "../src/scss/custom.scss";
```